# Saving Data from CSV files in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have created class for Database connection and database update:

```
   class DatabaseConnection
   {
    private string sql_string;
    private string strCon;
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter da;

    public string Sql { set { sql_string = value; } }
    public string connection_string { set { strCon = value; }}
    public System.Data.DataSet GetConnection{ get { return MyDataSet(); }}

    private System.Data.DataSet MyDataSet()
    {
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(strCon);
        con.Open();
        da = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sql_string, con);
        System.Data.DataSet dat_set = new System.Data.DataSet();
        da.Fill(dat_set, "Table_Data_1");
        con.Close();
        return dat_set;
    }

    public void UpdateDatabase(System.Data.DataSet ds)
    {
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder cb = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder(da);
        cb.DataAdapter.Update(ds.Tables[0]);
    }
}
```

And a program

```
        try
        {
            objConnect = new DatabaseConnection();
            conString = Properties.Settings.Default.GBMRainfallConnectionString;
            objConnect.connection_string = conString;
            objConnect.Sql = Properties.Settings.Default.SQL;
            ds = objConnect.GetConnection;
            MaxRows = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
            MessageBox.Show(MaxRows.ToString());
            //dRow = ds.Tables[0].Rows[100];
            //txtFirstName.Text = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(0).ToString();
            //txtSurname.Text = dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(1).ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
        }

        string CatchID = @"C:\Users\NKB\Desktop\GBMCatchments.txt";
        List<string> CatchmentName = new List<string>();
        var catchmet = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(CatchID));
        int x = 0;

        while (!catchmet.EndOfStream)
        {

            var line = catchmet.ReadLine();
            CatchmentName.Add(line);
            x = x + 1;
        }

        List<string> Date = new List<string>();
        List<string> CatchName = new List<string>();
        List<string> CatchRain = new List<string>();
        for (int j = 0; j < 360; j++)
        {

            string catchCSV = "C:\\Users\\NKB\\Desktop\\Catchments\\" + CatchmentName[j] + ".csv";

            var catchment = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(catchCSV));

            while (!catchment.EndOfStream)
            {
                var line = catchment.ReadLine();
                var values = line.Split(',');
                Date.Add(values[0]);
                CatchName.Add(CatchmentName[j]);
                CatchRain.Add(values[1]);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < CatchRain.Count; i++)
        {
            DataRow row = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
            row[0] = Date[i];
            row[1] = CatchName[i];
            row[2] = CatchRain[i];
            ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(row);
        }
        objConnect.UpdateDatabase(ds);
```

The data is saved in Database. But when I close the program, the database contains no data. Why is it occuring and what is the solution?

Comment: It shows that database updated but in the database, there the data is not showing????

Comment: Please add the code that initializes your DatabaseConnection class. In particular the connection string used

Comment: I have edited the query to show you the code that initializes DatabaseConnection Class.

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. I wish to see the connectionstring content. Does it contain the |DataDirectory| substitution string?

Comment: The connectionString is: Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Resources\GBMRainfall.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True

Comment: Then I wish you look at [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17147249/why-dont-changes-to-database-save/17147460#17147460) and check if this is your case

Comment: Not sure about "Up to the two level" in the solution.