# ASP.NET(VB) How to insert textbox.text into SQL database?

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net

I am designing a register form.
The following is my codes:
but after I do it, then the SQL table display is not the user's data....?
The database table display &username&, &password&
(username, password...are textboxes name)

```
Protected Sub btnOK_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOK.Click       
        Dim Conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(".....")
        Conn.Open()
        Dim sqlstr As String = "Insert Into user_profile(username,password,nickname,realname,email) Values('" & username.Text & "','" & password.Text & "','" & nickname.Text & "','" & realname.Text & "','" & email.Text & "')"
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sqlstr, Conn)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        cmd.Cancel()
        Conn.Close()
        Conn.Dispose()

    End Sub
```

Comment: You should really think of using SqlParameters, do not concatenate.

Comment: Hi. My username is `DROP TABLE user_profile; --` **Note** Don't use my username. [SQLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: A part from the Sql Injection issue, check if [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17147249/why-saving-changes-to-a-database-fails/17147460#17147460) applies to your situation

Comment: Little Bobby Tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, first, I'll take a stab at your question.  Then, we NEED to talk about SQL Injections.

Try this:

```
Dim MyValues as String = String.Format("'{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', '{4}'", username.Text, password.Text, nickname.Text, realname.Text, email.Text )

Dim sqlstr As String = "Insert Into user_profile(username,password,nickname,realname,email) Values(MyValues)"
```

(I've not tested that code.  Watch for syntax errors.)

Now, that having been said, it is VITAL that you understand the danger of the way you are trying to do this.  The serious problem here is that you are wide open to a SQL Injection attack.  Google it.  But in short, using this approach, someone can put commands like 'drop table' into your textbox, and those commands will be executed in your database.

The proper way to do this would be to create a stored procedure that contains the INSERT statement, and then pass your values to it with parameters.  The web is littered with tutorials on how to do this.  You'll find one easy enough.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much!
It is completed! Good!