# Unable to update SQL Database, Using C# Win Form

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, visual-studio-2013

My Application (C# Win Form) was working perfectly a while ago - i.e (Update, insert, delete...).
But after I close the program and open the Database there are no changes being made.

I'm not getting any errors during running.
I'm using VS2013 professional, SQL Database, C#.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conString)) 
{ 
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE [FullInk] SET [InStock] = '" + 
           newSum + "' Where [Catalog] = '" + catalog + "'"); 
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text; 
    cmd.Connection = connection; 
    connection.Open(); 
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();    
    connection.Close(); 
}
```

Comment: Mention/Provide Some code...so we can understand  and track problem

Comment: You are not committing your transactions and closing the application causes rollback to lose the changes?

Comment: Maybe this is the problem. but at first it worked and i didn't changed the code.

Comment: using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conString))
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE [FullInk] SET [InStock] = '" + newSum + "' Where [Catalog] = '" + catalog + "'");
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Connection = connection;
                    connection.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    connection.Close();
                }

Comment: this is example for UPDATE command i made.

Comment: can't find any issue in your code..can u check the value coming in newSum and catalog? may be the condition is failing thats why update is not happening

Comment: I have checked it. The value is fine. I have other forms in the project that i make changes and non of them is working anymore. The thing is that this code, as is, worked fine few days ago. I also making checking in the program and not getting error. it seems that the DB is changing but after i close the App all the changing not saved.

Comment: with out closing did u checked the DB?

Comment: I can't check the DB while the program runs. but i have section in the code that check the tables i update and its look fine..

Comment: you can check this question hope it helps [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17147249/why-saving-changes-to-a-database-fails/17147460#17147460]

Comment: Hi, I think I know what is my problem.. I have 2 files of .mdf. one at path: <projectName>\DataBase1.mdf and the other at path: <projectName>\bin\Debug\DataBase1.mdf. maybe my connectionString is not defined correctly?

Comment: I put it in the app.config like this: <add name="MyDB" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True"/>

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of any additional transaction such as a `TransactionScope` or `SqlTransaction` (which we can't see in your code), there is no reason why the update will be rolled back. I believe you might not actually be updating the data you think.

Although not necessarily the solution, it is much better practice to use parameterized queries rather than using strings - this has security (Sql Injection), performance (query plan caching) and also helps to eliminate bugs relating to quotes, escaping, and type conversion (which might be the case here - e.g. you are inserting `newSum` which could imply a numeric value into `InStock` using quotes, which implies a char type). e.g.

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(conString)) 
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE [FullInk] SET [InStock] = @InStock Where [Catalog] = @Catalog")) 
{ 
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text; 
    cmd.Connection = connection; 
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InStock", newSum);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Catalog", catalog);
    connection.Open(); 
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();    
}
```

Other minor modifications include disposing of the `SqlCommand`, and also note that disposing a connection will also close it, so you won't need to explicitly close it (although doing so won't hurt).

Answer (score 0):

Try This: It Might work for you...

```
    string Query = "UPDATE FullInk SET InStock = '" + newSum + "' Where Catalog = '" + catalog + "'";
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conString);
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, sql_con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();    
    connection.Close();
```

Also **add breakpoints**  and check weather your code is executing or not
Cause your code seems fine,& should be working