# SQL query does not update table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have got an `UPDATE` query, what works well when I execute it in MS Managment Studio.
But if I try execute this query from my c# app, it executes without any exceptions, but does not update the table. Connection string is right.
This is the way I do it:

```
int contractId = 2
con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\tst.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "update аренды set datetime_возврата=GETDATE() where id_договора=@contractId";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@contract_id", SqlDbType.Int, 4).Value = contractId;         
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

What can be wrong?

Comment: You add a named parameter `@contract_id` while the command text has `@contractId`. Might that be the case?

Comment: no, that is not the case. it does not works even if it is "update аренды set datetime_возврата=GETDATE() where id_договора=2"

Comment: Are you sure the problem isn't that you don't commit it and rollback happens? Maybe profiler helps you to see what actually happens.

Comment: I would also recommend checking the query that arrives to the server using SQL Server Profiler and comparing that to the one you executed in Management Studio.

Comment: Probably your answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17147249/why-saving-changes-to-a-database-fails/17147460#17147460 of course you need to fix the parameter name as explained in comments above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your c# code executes without any exceptions, it updates the database too, but please note you are used `AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\tst.mdf` in your `ConnectionString` means the database that is updated is located in the sub-folder `BIN\DEBUG` folder of your project. If you want to see the updated data just attach the database located in the `bin/debug` folder in SSMS.
Also as Steve mentioned in comments, for more details read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17147249/why-saving-changes-to-a-database-fails/17147460#17147460) post.