# Visual basic SQL database Connection String

Tags: sql, vb.net, connection-string

Well I have this 2 connections strings

1st
"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename='C:\Users\Cj\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\LS-Optical\LS-Optical\Database1.mdf';Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"

2nd
"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename='|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf';Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"

these 2 connect/open the database
but the 1st one Commits/saves the data using the app the.Second one save it  WHILE the program is RUNNING and losses all data inputed while app is runing when the app is closed(Rollbacks)

well ican use the first one but isnt it better if the connection string is dynamically change base on the app directory.

if this string is wrong any suggestions that actomatically detect directory?
PS igot the 1st one on server explorer database properties.....
the 2nd one is from when making dataSource/datasets....

This is a Windows Form

Comment: Is this project a windows app (winform, wpf) or a web app (ASP.NET etc..)?

Comment: You could take a [look at this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17147249/why-saving-changes-to-a-database-fails/17147460#17147460) and check if that is your case