# SQL command INSERT is working but the data not appear in table

Tags: c#, sql-server, insert, ado.net, sql-server-express

I am executing SQL command `INSERT` like this in my Visual C#.NET using MS VS 2010 Express Edition:

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.loginDBConnectionString);
     con.Open();
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblEmp (ID, firstname, lastname, email, position) VALUES ('"+textBox1.Text+"','"+textBox2.Text+"', '"+textBox3.Text+"', '"+textBox4.Text+"', '"+comboBox1.Text+"')", con);
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     con.Close();
     MessageBox.Show("Data Added!");
}
```

When executing this, the `MessageBox` showed up which means the execution was successful. But, when I checked on the table , the data that I am trying to insert before isn't appear at all.

I have one database (`loginDB.mdf`) with 2 tables inside :
- `TblLogin` - contains `username` and `password` for login purpose which executed successfully.
- `tblEmp` - contains employee data, this is the one that I tried to insert data to.

What I don't understand is why the `MessageBox` appear when in fact none inserted into my `tblEmp`.

**EDIT** : `ConnectionString` to `loginDB.mdf` :

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename="C:\Users\Andreas\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\LoginApplication\LoginApplication\loginDB.mdf";Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True
```

The database name is `loginDB.mdf` instead of `logindatabase.mdf` as previously written. I changed it to `loginDB.mdf` just to test it, but still no changes appear.

Comment: Please show your ConnectionString too.

Comment: Is `ID` an identity column which auto generates it's value on insert? Always use parameterized queries instead of string concatenation to build your sql queries. Otherwise ypou are vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: First thing to do apart from anything else: stop building SQL like that. Use parameterized SQL to avoid SQL injection attacks, avoid conversion problems, and make your code more readable.

Comment: You should **always** use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. Have you ever check as a return value for `ExecuteNonQuery` method? Is it returns `1` exactly? What is your variables? Have you ever tried your query in your database manager first?

Comment: Can you run a Sql Profiler and see what command is executed exactly? Also: Do the textboxes have values when you debug?

Comment: Also you should use `using` construction for `SqlConnection` (and for other `IDisposable`s).

Comment: Most probably you are looking for data in a wrong database.

Comment: Thx guys for all the answer you provided for me. I am still new to programming and did this simple C# app from youtube. How to use parameterized query ?

Comment: @MeanGreen - yes, it has value when I debug it by attaching break point on the sqlcommand line.  For Nikolay - the database is located in the same folder with the project, is it wrong ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your c# code executes without any exceptions, it updates the database too. You have probably used `AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\yourDB.mdf` in your `ConnectionString`, that means the databse that is updated is located in the subfolder `BIN\DEBUG` folder of your project. If you want to see the updated data just attach the database located in the `bin/debug` folder in ssms.
for more details read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17147249/why-saving-changes-to-a-database-fails/17147460#17147460) post.
Also make sure your table in server explorer is not already open, if it is already open you must refresh it to show updated data. Please note:as mentioned in the comments you should **always** use **parameterized queries** to avoid [`Sql Injection`.](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp)

Comment: Update : It is indeed like what you said, I am adding the database in **Bin\Debug** version and after testing, it appears. It just only 1 data that appear, like the database only write the latest inserted data and throw off the previous one so how many times I add data, it will only show 1 row of data in the database. How to change it ?

Comment: if you included your database as a file in your project, try set `Copy To Output Directory` property of DataBase to `Copy if newer` may help you. Please mark my answer as "accepted" if it was helpful for you. Also if you need more help let me know.http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Yes, finally I am manage to get all the things done and right. Thank you!