# MS Access Update Query Not Working

Tags: c#, ms-access

I can't Figure out what is wrong with the query, but it is not updating any value in the Table

```
string qry = "UPDATE Stock SET  Itemname=@n,Unit=@u,Price=@p,Tax=@t,Balance=@b,Status=@s Where Sid=@sid";
OleDbCommand ocmd = new OleDbCommand(qry,BBC);
ocmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@n", name);
ocmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@u", unit);
ocmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p", price);
ocmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@t", tax);
ocmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", balance);
ocmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@s", status);
ocmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sid", sid);
ocmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

`Price`,`Tax` and `Balance` are `Decimal` values.

I did debug and its working fine but just not updating the value.

Comment: are you getting any error or exceptions?

Comment: did you debug? values are ok that you set to parameters ?

Comment: it is not giving any error , and yes i did debug and its working fine but just not updating the value

Comment: can you share how your variables are defined for values?

Comment: public void UpdateStock (string sid, string name, string unit, decimal price, decimal tax, decimal balance, string status) and the sid is a GUID

Comment: Try putting your code in a try catch block to see if there are any exceptions

Comment: no the code is clean o tried it

Comment: Have a look at this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31604951/sql-command-insert-is-working-but-the-data-not-appear-in-table

Comment: i tried pasting the accdb  file in bin\debug folder but still nothing

Comment: It did worked, i didt do anything

Answer (score 0):

set the type of each parameter and execute the query.

```
List<OleDbParameter> paramList = new List<OleDbParameter>();

OleDbParameter param = new OleDbParameter("@param", OleDbType.TypeName);

param.Value = value;

paramList.Add(param);

ocmd.Parameters.AddRange(paramArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do it for you.

```
string ConnString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\\your_path_here\test.accdb";
using(OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConnString ))
using(OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
   cmd.CommandText = @ "UPDATE Stock SET  Itemname=@n,Unit=@u,Price=@p,Tax=@t,Balance=@b,Status=@s Where Sid=@sid";

   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@n", txtItemName.Text);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@u", txtUnit.Text);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p", Convert.ToDecimal(txtPrice.Text));
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@t", Convert.ToDecimal(txtTax.Text));
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", Convert.ToDecimal(txtBalance.Text));
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@s", txtStatus.Text);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sid", txtSID.Text);

   conn.Open();
   int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   conn.Close();
}
```