# Not able to perform insert query operation

Tags: c#, sql

I am working on my simple task in c# with service based database. I have a service-based database where I have table `staff` with columns id, name and password. I am trying to insert new record into that table, with C# code, but it's not inserting, just telling me "No Record ADDED" even there is no error.

My code is:

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        connetionString = Properties.Settings.Default.testdbConnectionString;
        cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);

        cnn.Open();

        SqlCommand command6;
        string sql6 = null;
        sql6 = "insert into staff (name,pwd,id) values(@n,@p,@fid)";

        command6 = new SqlCommand(sql6, cnn);
        command6.Parameters.AddWithValue("@n", "jhon");
        command6.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p", "test");
        command6.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fid", 1);

        int result = command6.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (result == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Record ADDED");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No Record ADDED");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

If you need more detail you my ask but please correct my mistake. Thanks

Comment: [Sock puppet account](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48489426). perhaps you could read [ask] and take the [tour] to learn how to ask a good question and save time creating multiple accounts

Comment: @Plutonix whats Wrong in my question ? Any incomplete detail ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of [ExecuteNonQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx) is the number of records affected. Your `if` statement is the wrong way round... if the result *doesn't* equal zero then something *was* inserted.

Comment: still same problem, now new row is inserted in table i checked manually

Comment: But if you're saying that you see "No Record ADDED" from the code above that means the result of ExecuteNonQuery wasn't zero... From MSDN: "Executes a Transact-SQL statement against the connection and returns the number of rows affected"

Comment: let forget result of messagebox just tell why he is not inserting values ?

Comment: I'm afraid I can only comment on what is posted, and from the code above and your description of the observed result, a row _should_ have been added. It's not going to be easy to attempt to determine why a row _wasn't_ added when the API you are using is suggesting otherwise.

Comment: select query is working fine while insert query have this stupid problem, is it problem of storing new row is in bin\debug\testdb.mdf while selecting from project\testdb.mdf

Comment: Reading from a different database than you are inserting into would definitely result in what you are seeing...

Comment: follow this link to solve this type of problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31604951/sql-command-insert-is-working-but-the-data-not-appear-in-table

Comment: i appreciate and admit your try for my help