# ASP.NET C# Deleting from access database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, ms-access

I've created a gridview that contains a "DELETE" button, to delete the row.

My Code :

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string username = (string)Session["user"];
    string path = this.GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text;
    Cart cart = new Cart();
    cart.Deleteitem(path,username);
}

public void Deleteitem(string path, string username)
{
    string sql = string.Format("DELETE FROM Cart WHERE path = '{0}' AND userid = '{1}' ", path, username);
    DBC dbc = new DBC();
    dbc.InsertUpdateDelete(sql);
}

 public void InsertUpdateDelete(string sql)
{
    this.cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, this.con);
    this.con.Open();
    this.cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    this.con.Close();
}
```

My problem that when I clock the "DELETE" button, nothing happen, nothing deleted, what's the problem ?

Comment: Have you checked your database after deletion, to see if it has updated? If your DB has updated, so probably your `GridView` doesn't refresh it's data.

Comment: are you implementing any gridview RowDeleting event ?. Also Put the debug point and check your sql delete statement

Comment: Re-select all records or refresh however you are binding the grid after the deletion.

Comment: Another possibility would be https://stackoverflow.com/a/31605045/2946329

Comment: I've checked my database, nothing changed, but another methods like : Insert, working without any problem ..

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you're probably throwing an error but you don't see it. Wrap your call to `this.cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` in a try...catch...finally block then step through it and see if you catch an error.

I've seen "errors" prevent an update but they aren't true errors - like the language being set to English instead of Default.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the single quotes around `{}`.

```
string.Format("DELETE FROM Cart WHERE path = {0} AND userid = {1}", path, username);
```

Comment: If userid is a number, just remove the quotes around that one. Note also that you're passing in `username` but your sql says `userid`.