# Can't seem to insert date into SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, winforms, ssms

I have created a table `tblAttendence` in the database that has 2 columns: `Date` (`datetime`) and `RegNo` (`int`). I have to insert the *current date & time* and a registration number from a label in the form.

C# code:

```
private void btnMarkAtt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        sqlCon.Open();

        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("MarkAtt", sqlCon);
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", DateTime.Now);
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RegNo", int.Parse(lblRegNo.Text));

        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        MessageBox.Show("Attendance marked successfully!");
    }
}
```

Stored procedure `MarkAtt`:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MarkAtt]
    @Date DATETIME,
    @RegNo INT
AS
    INSERT INTO tblAttendence(Date, RegNo)
    VALUES (@Date, @RegNo)
```

There is no error shown in the code. The debugging doesn't stop to show an error. When I press the button, just nothing happens (neither the data is inserted, nor the message box is shown).

I can't seem to find out what is going on. The connection string is correct (I have used it in the same form and it works). Is there something wrong with the connection? Or the stored procedure? Or anything else that I am missing?

Comment: This might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31604951/sql-command-insert-is-working-but-the-data-not-appear-in-table

Comment: Where is your database located? Is this as a file in your project or separately with SQL Server?

Comment: can u monitor your sql server with with sql server profiler? it will show you what queries are sent for witch database and what happens there.

Comment: +1 for the sql server profiler. It would show you all the execution depending on the request. On the other hand, your tblAttendance table might have a trigger of some sort. You might want to check that out.

Comment: @VikramKumar The database is on a server. I created the tables using ssms

Comment: Are you certain that the function `btnMarkAtt_Click` and the click event of the button are tied together?

Comment: @JayV Yes, I checked that. They are bound together.

Comment: @yekanchi I checked sql server profiler. It doesn't show any new event when I press the button.

Comment: @rockin' Sql server profiler doesn't show that any new event is created. What do you mean by _a trigger of some sort_ ?

Comment: @Psyikik tables have "Triggers" such as "insert","update","delete". I thought it might be a good idea to check if there's an "insert" trigger that manipulates / removes the newly inserted row. But since the Profiler didn't show any events, my suggestion is obselete.

Comment: @yekanchi: it's **which** - not "witch" (that's an old lady on a broomstick flying through the air .....)

Comment: My guess is that, lblRegNo.Text is not parsable as an integer and the error is catched and silenced in your code. Can you try your code isolated in LinqPad, with a manually input RegNo.Text like "99". Code looks to be perfectly valid.

Comment: Could it be as simple as btnMarkAtt_Click not being hooked up or not hooked up to the expected button? Try placing a breakpoint on top of that method to see that your method is being called..

Comment: I see several possibilities: 1) the eventhandler for the button click is not properly registered. Thus your code is not called at all. 2) Your DB connection is failing and the respective exception is caught somewhere else and not reported 3) lbRegNo.Text is not a valid integer and the respective exception is caught somewhere else.  Try setting a breakpoint in your method and step through it line by line

Comment: _Nothing_ happens? Put a breakpoint on the very first line of your code and step through.