# Saving DataGridView multiple row data into SQL Server LocalDB not working

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview, localdb

I'm trying to INSERT multiple row data into LocalDB from DataGridView. It doesn't show any errors. And I cant see inserted data in database. Below is my code. Code works with MySQL. But I have migrated to MSSQL. What can be the reason? Am I doing wrong?

```
private void SaveToStockButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    Conn.Open();

                    // save DataGridView multiple row data in to MSSQL database
                    for (int i = 0; i < InsertDataGridView.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {

                        string item_name = InsertDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                        string item_code = InsertDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                        string purchase_qty = InsertDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();



                        string Query = "INSERT INTO inventory ([item_name], [item_code], [purchase_qty]) VALUES ('"
                            + item_name + "','"
                            + item_code + "','"
                            + purchase_qty + "');";
                        SqlCommand SQLcmd = new SqlCommand(Query, Conn);
                        SQLcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    }

                    string Query2 = "INSERT INTO summary ([sup_inv], [supplier], [inv_total], [date]) VALUES ('"
                            + SupplierInvNoBox.Text + "','"
                            + SupplierNameBox.Text + "','"
                            + InsertTotalBox.Text + "','"
                            + PurchasedDateBox.Text + "');";
                    SqlCommand SQLcmd2 = new SqlCommand(Query2, Conn);
                    SQLcmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    Conn.Close();

                    // RefreshButton.PerformClick();


                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message+ " SaveToStockButton_Click");

            }


           // MessageBox.Show("Saved!");
        }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31605045/2946329

Comment: @Salah Akbari
 my connectionstring was, `string connectionString = Settings.Default["MainDBConString"].ToString();` that was the problem. Solved. Thank you! :)

Comment: Did you place a breakpoint at  `SQLcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`, so that you could check it's executed? Also you're making as many transactions as there are rows to be updated, which is very bad move. You should compile your SQL code and then fire it up at once in one transaction. This way it might be aslo easier to debug.