# C# Can't modify a database

Tags: c#, database, commit

I'm currently trying to modify a local database using a C# program. I followed this example : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction.commit.aspx

The problem is that the modification is done when the program is running (for instance, if I add a new row, I will see it in my program), but when I stop the program and I check the database, there is no change anymore - the database is exactly the same as before the execution.

I've been working on this issue for several days and haven't found a solution.

Here is an extract of my work:

```
SqlConnection connectionLocale = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|LocalDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True");

SqlCommand command2 = connectionLocale.CreateCommand();
SqlTransaction transaction;

connectionLocale.Open();
transaction = connectionLocale.BeginTransaction();

command2.Connection = connectionLocale;
command2.Transaction = transaction;

try
{
    command2.CommandText = "DELETE FROM Chercheur";
    command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
    transaction.Commit();
    Console.WriteLine("commit ok");
}
catch
{
    transaction.Rollback();
}

connectionLocale.Close();
```

I'm using Visual Vtudio 2012 with a .mdf database.

After some research I saw somewhere that the connection `(AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|LocalDB.mdf)` creates a temporary database and that all the change are done on this temporary database.

How can I affect the original database instead of this temporary database?

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17147249/why-saving-changes-to-a-database-fails/17147460#17147460

Answer (score 1):

To persist changes you need to put the database on a real SQL Server and change your connection string to something like: `Server=someServerName; Database=someDatabaseName; Trusted_Connection=true` or `Server=someServerName; Database=someDatabaseName; User ID=someSqlUser; Password=somePassword`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to point your connection string to the *correct* instance (the "original database"):

```
SqlConnection connectionLocale = new SqlConnection("Data Source = YourInstanceName; initial catalog = YourDatabaseName; Integrated Security=True");
```

Substituting the following values:

**YourInstanceName** - the name of the SQL Server instance where your database lives (can be obtained from `select @@servername;` while connected to the SQL instance)

**YourDatabaseName** - the name of the database where you want to modify the data

The connection string tells the provider ***where*** to target your queries.  If you're not pointing to the correct destination SQL Server instance (and database), then you'll get the undesirable results that you're experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string is pointing to the local db.  Your connection string -

```
"Data Source=(LocalDB)\\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|LocalDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
```

must be changed to point to your actual db.

Take a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e38h511e(v=VS.71).aspx) for a process to generate your connection string.
You could also refer to [connectionstring.com](http://connectionstrings.com) for sample connection strings.