# Insert into access database not working

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I'm using Visual Studio 2015, Visual Basic Language.
I want to INSERT INTO an Access Database a username ('Utilizador' in the code).
This is the code I have:

```
Try
    Dim nconnect As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OleDb.12.0;" & "Data Source =|DataDirectory|S_Campo.accdb")
    nconnect.Open()
    Dim ncmd As OleDbCommand = nconnect.CreateCommand()
    ncmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Utilizador (Nome) VALUES (@p1)"
    ncmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", Me.TextBox5.Text) 'Nome Do Utilizador
    ncmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    nconnect.Close()
    MsgBox("Utilizador lançado com êxito", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Informação")

Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(Err.Description)
End Try
```

It doesn't return me any error message, but the Data is not sent to the Database.
However, UPDATE, and DELETE is working fine, using 'Parameters'.

What can is wrong with it?

Comment: `VB` & `VB.NET` are different, it looks like you're using `VB.NET` here.

Comment: How are you determining that it isnt inserting?  The DB appears to be part of the project, what is the `Copy to Output Directory` setting?

Comment: Sorry Plutonix, but I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that you have parameter issue. Here

```
ncmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Utilizador (Nome) VALUES (@p1)"
```

your parameter is `@p1`. And here

```
ncmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", Me.TextBox5.Text) 'Nome Do Utilizador
```

it is `@1`

In any case, here how you should check for success

```
If ncmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0 Then
    MessageBox.Show("Success!!")
End If
```

Comment: No it is not a parameter problem. OleDb doesn't use names for the parameters but the position. You could name them whatever you like,

Comment: @Steve This is the only thing I see "abnormal" here. My true belief that OP simply not checking in the right place that data is inserted. Hence my second part `ExecuteNonQuery() > 0`

Comment: Instead I think the problem lies in the DataDirectory substitution string and the combined behavior of the _Copy To Output Directory_ property as hinted above from Plutonix and explained in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17147249/why-saving-changes-to-a-database-fails/17147460#17147460)

Comment: I solved this problem with 2 changes: 1- I changed the path, from a relative to a absolut one. 2- I corrected the parameter, as T.S. sugestion. Now it's working fine. Thank you for your concern.