# How do I save data in my database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I have made a datagridview with data from database, then I have 3 different forms with insert data, delete data, etc.

The problem is that when I'm trying to insert data and restart the program, the data doesn't get saved.

Here is my code:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");

con.Open();

string sql = "INSERT INTO Elevi (Nume, Prenume, SportulPracticat) VALUES(@nume, @prenume, @sport)";

using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nume", textBox1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prenume", textBox2.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sport", textBox3.Text);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

con.Close();
```

Comment: Have you run this in debug mode to see what's happening? The way it's written, it looks like as soon as `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` is executed, you should have a row inserted into the table.

Comment: Probably it is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17147249/why-saving-changes-to-a-database-fails/17147460#17147460

Comment: Yes.i run it into the Debug mode.And i do have the row inserted.But it doesnt save.As soon as I press X button and run the dubug again,the row inserted dissapears.

Comment: No,Steve.It is not.I tried doing that without success.

Comment: Let me ask you another clarification. ExecuteNonQuery returns the number of rows affected. Could you get that value and tell us if it is zero or one? If it is one then your record has been inserted and some other mechanism causes you record to disappear, not this code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole *User Instance and AttachDbFileName=* approach is flawed - at best! When running your app in Visual Studio, it will be copying around the `.mdf` file (from your `App_Data` directory to the output directory - typically `.\bin\debug` - where you app runs) and **most likely**, your `INSERT` works just fine - but you're just looking at the **wrong .mdf file** in the end!

If you want to stick with this approach, then try putting a breakpoint on the `myConnection.Close()` call - and then inspect the `.mdf` file with SQL Server Mgmt Studio Express - I'm almost certain your data is there.

The **real solution** in my opinion would be to

1. install SQL Server Express (and you've already done that anyway)
2. install SQL Server Management Studio Express
3. create your database in **SSMS Express**, give it a logical name (e.g. `YourDatabase`)
4. connect to it using its logical **database name** (given when you create it on the server) - and don't mess around with physical database files and user instances. In that case, your connection string would be something like:

   ```
   Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=YourDatabase;Integrated Security=True
   ```

   and everything else is **exactly** the same as before...

Also see Aaron Bertrand's excellent blog post [Bad habits to kick: using AttachDbFileName](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-attachdbfilename/) for more background info.

Answer (score 0):

I can't spot any error. Maybe you're looking on the wrong piece of code.
If idata vanish from db when starting the debug perhaps you should look to what happens before or after (do you perform a deletion or a truncate?).

Answer (score -1):

Try adding a COMMIT; command to the SQL code

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
SqlTransaction trans = con.BeginTransaction();
con.Open();
string sql = "INSERT INTO Elevi (Nume , Prenume , SportulPracticat) VALUES(@nume,@prenume,@sport)";
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
{
    cmd.Transaction = trans;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nume", textBox1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prenume", textBox2.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sport", textBox3.Text);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    trans.Commit();
}
con.Close();
```