# Changes To Data Set Not Saving

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, dataset

When I add a new row to my data set it is visible on that specific form in the datagridview, however when I switch to another form with the same data bound datagridview the new row is not there. When I close the program my new row is completely gone then. I want to to save the new row to the Access database it is reading from.

```
Public Class frmAddStudent




Private Sub btnBack_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBack.Click
    Me.Hide()
    frmUserControls.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub frmAddStudent_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'StudentRecords1DataSet.tblLecturer' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.TblLecturerTableAdapter.Fill(Me.StudentRecords1DataSet.tblLecturer)
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'StudentRecords1DataSet.tblStudents' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.TblStudentsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.StudentRecords1DataSet.tblStudents)

End Sub

Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click

    Dim MyNewRow As DataRow
    MyNewRow = StudentRecords1DataSet.tblStudents.NewRow



    Try

        With MyNewRow
            .Item(1) = txtID.Text
            .Item(2) = txtFirstName.Text
            .Item(3) = txtSurname.Text


        End With



        Me.Validate()
        Me.TblStudentsBindingSource.EndEdit() 'Change this to your binding source ' eg table'
        Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.StudentRecords1DataSet) ' chnage this to your database name'
        MessageBox.Show("The Data Has Been Saved", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
    Catch ex As Exception
        'if there is a problem saving the data, it will show a messagebox with the problem as to why it could'nt save the data'
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try

    StudentRecords1DataSet.tblStudents.Rows.Add(MyNewRow)
    StudentRecords1DataSet.tblStudents.AcceptChanges()

End Sub

Private Sub txtFirstName_MaskInputRejected(sender As Object, e As MaskInputRejectedEventArgs)

End Sub

Private Sub TblStudentsBindingNavigator_RefreshItems(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TblStudentsBindingNavigator.RefreshItems

End Sub
```

End Class

Any suggestions please?

Comment: have you added your access database to your project?

Comment: @Werdna ye, the access db is added through the `Add New DataSource` function

Comment: and you just want a button to save the database yea?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17147249/why-saving-changes-to-a-database-fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATe X2 based off your question update.
try this,

```
Public Class frmAddStudent


Private Sub btnBack_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBack.Click
    Me.Hide()
    frmUserControls.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub frmAddStudent_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'StudentRecords1DataSet.tblLecturer' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.TblLecturerTableAdapter.Fill(Me.StudentRecords1DataSet.tblLecturer)
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'StudentRecords1DataSet.tblStudents' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.TblStudentsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.StudentRecords1DataSet.tblStudents)

End Sub

Private Async Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click

    Try
        Me.Validate()
        Me.TblStudentsBindingSource.EndEdit() 'Change this to your binding source ' eg table'
        Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.StudentRecords1DataSet) ' chnage this to your database name'
        MessageBox.Show("The Data Has Been Saved", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
        Await Task.Delay(100)
        TblStudentsBindingNavigator_RefreshItems.studentsBindingSource.AddNew()
    Catch ex As Exception
        'if there is a problem saving the data, it will show a messagebox with the problem as to why it could'nt save the data'
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub txtFirstName_MaskInputRejected(sender As Object, e As MaskInputRejectedEventArgs)

End Sub

Private Sub TblStudentsBindingNavigator_RefreshItems(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TblStudentsBindingNavigator.RefreshItems

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: I have added in that Try Catch, however I am still having the same issue of the data not saving to my db. Your message box saying the data has saved is appearing but rows are not actually being saved

Comment: can you add all of your code to your question please? there must be a problem somewhere else, yeah it will save completed if the database hasn't been setup correctly.

Comment: did you drag the grid across from "Data Sources"?

Comment: also the way you have it making a new row is incorrect, you should try something like `Customers_InformationBindingSource.AddNew()` and it will automatically add a new row for the access database.

Comment: Yes that grid is dragged across and so were the text boxes

Comment: if it doesnt work, feel free to email me your code and access datafile and i will take a look for you :)

Comment: Pasted in your new answer, getting an eror with `TblStudentsBindingNavigator_RefreshItems.studentsBindingSource.AddNew()` . Error is `Argument not specified for parameter 'sender' of 'Private Sub TblStudentsBindingNavigator_RefreshItems(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs`

Comment: send me your project with the access data file and ill have a real look for you. = andreweberle@outlook.com

Comment: Sent! Let me know how you get on

Comment: OK, i have sent you an email with an example i have made up, i think the problem you have is with your database from Access, let me know how you go :) Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a million for all your help @Werdna, greatly appreciated and I understand the VB to DataBase a lot better now!! `(Y)`

Comment: @Donncha no problem at all, happy to help :)