# Access Database Doesn't update properly

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access, oledb

I have been creating a software in C#. I tried to update some information in my Access database. Here's my database fields.`Date` ,`total_h`, `W_hours`, `delay_h`. `Date` is the Primary key. So I want to Update data where `Date="datetimePicker.text"`.   here is the Code What I tried.

```
try
{
    connection.Open();
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
    cmd.Connection = connection;               
    string update = "update summery_data set total_h='"+tHour+"', delay_h='"+delay+"' WHERE Date= " + dateTimePicker1.Text + " ";      
                    cmd.CommandText = update;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show(" Updated successfully");
                    connection.Close();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

The Program is running properly without any Exception and displaying the "Updated successfully" message also. But when I open and Check the database the data has not been updated. I can't Understand what the problem is...?. please help me someone knows about it.

Comment: You are looking at a copy of the database.  See the DataDictionary path in your connection string.  That's a lousy query.  Always use parameters to avoid sql injection and avoid formatting errors.

Comment: What are the types of your columns?

Comment: date:-date/time total_h:-Text , W_hours:-Text, delay_h:-text

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why saving changes to a database fails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17147249/why-saving-changes-to-a-database-fails).  Plenty of things wrong in that though,

Answer (score 1):

change

```
string update = ".... WHERE Date= " + dateTimePicker1.Text + " ";
```

to

```
string update = ".... WHERE Date= DateValue ('" + dateTimePicker1.Text + "') ";
```