# Unable to insert to SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net

```
using (Connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))                
{
    SqlCommand voegtoe = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Speler(Naam, Rugnummer, Leeftijd) VALUES(@Naam, @Rugnummer, @Leeftijd)");

    voegtoe.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    voegtoe.Connection = Connection;
    voegtoe.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Naam", textBox1.Text);
    voegtoe.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rugnummer", textBox2.Text);
    voegtoe.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Leeftijd", textBox3.Text);

    Connection.Open();
    voegtoe.ExecuteNonQuery();            
}
```

If I open my Database there's nothing added to it. I think it should add the text what the user puts in the textboxes.

The connection string is:

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirector‌​y|\Speler.mdf;Integr‌​ated Security=True
```

Comment: Check if your situation is like the one described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17147249/why-saving-changes-to-a-database-fails/17147460#17147460

Comment: Surround it with a try-catch and set a breakpoint in the catch

Comment: Are you targeting the correct database? What is your connection string? Are you trying to store in a file-based database perhaps?

Comment: connectionstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["KillerApp1.Properties.Settings.SpelerConnectionString"].ConnectionString;   I found out that the problem is somewhere between the connection, because the database doesn't connect correctly

Comment: @k.Sonnemans that's *not* the connection string. It's the code you use to load the connection string from your settings. What is the connection string? Does it use `AttachDbFilename` perhaps, to load a local database?

Comment: using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace KillerApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SqlConnection Connection;
        string connectionstring;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            connectionstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["KillerApp1.Properties.Settings.SpelerConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        }

Comment: I repeat, that is **NOT** the connection string. That code loads the connection string from your app.config or web.config file. What is the connection string store in there? It's name is `SpelerCon‌​nectionString` and also appears in your `Project > Properties > Settings` tab

Comment: You mean this one:   Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Speler.mdf;Integrated Security=True  I'm sorry this is new to me so i dont know much about it..

Comment: Yes. I wrote the answer while waiting, since `AttachDbFilename` is the culprit in almost all similar cases.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p2UeT7dBTEg   i followed this YouTube guide but there's an error on the ExecuteNonQuery. It says: connection is not initialised

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with the code. I suspect that your connection string uses a User instance database, ie it has the `AttachDBFilename` and `User Instance=true` keywords:

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\db.mdf; User Instance=true;...
```

That means that each user that tries to attach to the database file gets his own copy. When you try to check the data with SSMS you see a *different* copy of the database.

Apart from causing confusion, this feature is deprecated and will be removed in the future.

Just create a proper database in your database server and connect to it by specifying its name:

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=MyDB;...
```

You can create the database either from the `New Database` menu in SSMS, or with a `CREATE DATABASE MyDB` command

You can find more information in [Bad habits : Using AttachDBFileName](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-attachdbfilename/) by Aaron Bertrand