# Any changes made to my database file are lost once i close my application and then restart

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview, bindingsource

I have been struggling with question for some time now and I have tried Everything. there are similar questions on stack overflow but I have tired all solutions none of them worked for me. The problem is changes are not stored on the data base file after I call the data source binding. below is the code snippet for save button

```vb
Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click

    If isValidData() = True Then ' sub routine that checks data inputted into textboxes is valid.
        Try
            ' i get data from the textboxes on form which are binded to the bindingsource viewplanet... 
            Me.ViewPlanetAlliancesBindingSource.EndEdit()
            Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.DsLab4)
            MessageBox.Show("Successfully Saved Data Row")
            Call updateViewPlanetAlliance()

        Catch ex As DBConcurrencyException
            MessageBox.Show("A concurrency erro occured. " & "the row was not deleted.", "Concurrency Exception")
            Me.ViewPlanetAlliancesTableAdapter.FillByRegionID(DsLab4.viewPlanetAlliances, CInt(Me.lstRegion.SelectedValue))

        Catch ex As ArgumentException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Argument exception")
            Me.ViewPlanetAlliancesBindingSource.CancelEdit()
        Catch ex As DataException
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, ex.GetType.ToString)
                Me.ViewPlanetAlliancesBindingSource.CancelEdit()
            End Try

        Else
            Try
                Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.DsLab4)
            Catch ex As DBConcurrencyException
                MessageBox.Show("A concurrency erro occured. " & "the row was not deleted.", "Concurrency Exception")
            Me.ViewPlanetAlliancesTableAdapter.FillByRegionID(DsLab4.viewPlanetAlliances, CInt(Me.lstRegion.SelectedValue))
        End Try

        End If

End Sub
```

This is what my form looks like and how my data is displayed

[image]

Comment: Do you get an error? If so, then where is it being caused and what does it tell you?

Comment: What database engine are you using?  How are you checking to see if there is data in the database after you close your app?

Comment: no I don't get any error in saving database. other than data validation which are resolved by isValid function

Comment: Very likely duplicate of [Why saving changes to a database fails?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17147249/1070452)

Comment: I have added the form image of how i am taking the data from textboxes which are binded to the viewplanetbindingsource

Comment: @Plutonix I have seen that question and I did made change suggested on that question of changing database file property to "copy only if newer" that did not fix my problem

Comment: The way to tell if it updated is to use the return from the Update *function* not the absence of an exception.  You still havent told us which DB this is, so that is about as much help as you can get short of WAGs

Comment: I am using the local SQL database file. to see updated results i check the datagridview which is connected to the binding source

Comment: You are better off verifying that the data has been written by looking at it, not using your application.  For example, it it's sql server, use ssms.

Comment: The way to tell if your code succeeds in adding/updating is to check the return from the Update functions.  If it says it added/updated N rows, it did.  If you cant see the added/changed row(s) in a DB Browser like SSMS (*not* your code), then you are looking at a different instance than the code is using.  If it is there, but then gone the next time you run, see the link.

Comment: Get away from the typed Data sets and Table adapters, they are buggy. Use pure SQL or Entity Framework, way more solid options.