# C# Not saving data in MS Access Database

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

I am developing a C# windows form application. This simple application is basically a form where the user can save, edit and delete some data in a MS Access database. When I debug the code, it works properly (I save the data end it appears as a new line in datagridview). The problem is that when I close the form and open it again, the datagridview do not show the record I just saved, and the new record is not saved in MS Access database. Here is the code I using to save the record:

```
private void btnSalvar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {                
            materiaisBindingSource.EndEdit();
            materiaisTableAdapter.Update(this.appData.Materiais);
            this.appData.Materiais.AcceptChanges();                                                   
            groupBox1.Enabled = false;
         }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Mensagem", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            materiaisBindingSource.ResetBindings(false);
        }
    }
```

Please, can someone help me?

Comment: Your'e just updating a local data source, you never update the database.

Comment: Probably a case of [Why saving changes to a database fails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17147249/why-saving-changes-to-a-database-fails/17147460#17147460) Please check

Comment: Thank you a lot @Steve ! I just changed the property Copy to output directory to **copy if newer**.