# C# Access Update Command Doesn't Work

Tags: c#, ms-access

I don't know what am I doing wrong but I tried everything I found on net, the code doesn't give any errors but also doesn't update database.

UPDATED:I solved the problem with taking @no to [] brackets

Here is code :`

```
String query = "UPDATE Kitaplık SET kitapAdi=@ad,kitapYazari=@yazar,kitapYayinevi=@yayinevi,sayfaSayisi=@sayfaSayisi where no=@no";
con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.Oledb.12.0;Data Source=Kutuphane.accdb");
cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ad", kitapAdiText.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yazar", kitapYazariText.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yayinevi", kitapYayıneviText.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sayfaSayisi", Convert.ToInt32(sayfaSayisiText.Text));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@no", Convert.ToInt32(noText.Text));
con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
listBox1.Items.Clear();
bilgileriCek();
```

Thanks for the answers!

Comment: wrap your `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery` around a `try{}catch(OleDBException ex){ }` and tell us what `ex.Message;` error is also when working with `OleDB` you may need to replace `@` with `?` in the update statement parameters.

Comment: I'm checking it on database file , it didn't update there too.

Comment: It doesn't give any error message when i do that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why saving changes to a database fails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17147249/why-saving-changes-to-a-database-fails)

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: If there really are no exceptions then most likely the `WHERE` clause is filtering out all rows or it is actually updating a row but you just think it should be a different one. `ExecuteNonQuery` returns the number of rows affected by the update. Set that to a variable and check its value.

Comment: It returns "0" value

Comment: Then I would say the value of `@no` matches no rows in the table. Use the debugger to get the value of `@no` then run a manual query in Access to see if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

OP "solved the problem with taking (changing) @no to [] brackets."