# Localdb doesn't save changes

Tags: sql-server, entity, localdb

I have a localdb that is working just fine on my development machine, however when I tried to test the app on another machine, I found that somehow changes do not take effect on the dB.
What could make entity framework behave differently on my machine than in the other one?

Here is my DbContext

```
public DataContext() : base("name=DBConnectionString")
{
    Database.SetInitializer(new DataInitializer());
}
```

And the DataInitializer class:

```
public class DataInitializer: DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<DataContext>
{
    public DataInitializer()
    {
    }

    protected override void Seed(DataContext context)
    {
        //Insert some seed data
        Console.WriteLine("Seeding db...");
        ...
        base.Seed(context);
    }
}
```

and the connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DeltaDBConnectionString"
        connectionString="Server=(localdb)\v11.0;Integrated Security=true;
        AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|\DeltaDB.mdf;"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: seems a permission issue.

Comment: how can I fix it?

Comment: the mdf file is created normally but changes do not commit.

Comment: right click the folder and check the permission, make sure your service account has read/write access on it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why saving changes to a database fails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17147249/why-saving-changes-to-a-database-fails)