# My SQL Server of Visual Studio (localdb) is not reflecting any changes or update

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-2016-localdb

My SQL Srver of Visual Studio (localdb) is not reflecting any changes or update. I am making some updates at the run time. It is eventually getting saved but when I am viewing data by option of view data there is no update in my table. Please Help.

Comment: Perhaps this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17147249/why-saving-changes-to-a-database-fails) about using substitution strings in your connection is relevant.

Comment: your welcome! please read this : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and get tour here : https://stackoverflow.com/tour then edit your question for give good answers and feedback