# SQL Server Express database table not updating

Tags: c#, sql-server

I wonder why my SQL Server Express database table doesn't get updated when the method below executes successfully?

```
public void addUser(User user)
{
    string query = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, firstname, lastname, isactive, accesslevel) VALUES (@usr,  @psw, @fname, @lname, @status, @access)";

    pSqlConn = new SqlConnection(pConnectingString);

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, pSqlConn);

    SqlParameter pmtrUsername = new SqlParameter("@usr", user.Username);
    SqlParameter pmtrPassword = new SqlParameter("@psw", user.Password);
    SqlParameter pmtrFirstname = new SqlParameter("@fname", user.Firstname);
    SqlParameter pmtrLastname = new SqlParameter("@lname", user.Lastname);
    SqlParameter pmtrStatus = new SqlParameter("@status", user.IsActive);
    SqlParameter pmtrAccessLevel = new SqlParameter("@access", user.AccessLevel);

    cmd.Parameters.Add(pmtrFirstname);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(pmtrLastname);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(pmtrUsername);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(pmtrPassword);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(pmtrStatus);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(pmtrAccessLevel);

    pSqlConn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Success!");
    pSqlConn.Close();
}
```

Comment: What does your **connection string** look like?

Comment: private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DatabaseConnection DB = new DatabaseConnection();
            DB.ConnectingString = Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectingString;
            DB.addUser(user);
        }

Comment: And what **value** is strong in the settings for your connection string??

Comment: Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\storemanagerdb.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30

Comment: Please [edit] additional information directly into your question.

Answer (score 1):

The whole *User Instance and AttachDbFileName=* approach is flawed - at best! When running your app in Visual Studio, it will be copying around the `.mdf` file (from your `App_Data` directory to the output directory - typically `.\bin\debug` - where you app runs) and **most likely**, your `INSERT` works just fine - but you're just looking at the **wrong .mdf file** in the end!

If you want to stick with this approach, then try putting a breakpoint on the `myConnection.Close()` call - and then inspect the `.mdf` file with SQL Server Mgmt Studio - I'm almost certain your data is there.

The **real solution** in my opinion would be to

1. install SQL Server Express (and you've already done that anyway)
2. install SQL Server Management Studio Express
3. create your database in **SSMS Express**, give it a logical name (e.g. `StoreManagerDB`)
4. connect to it using its logical **database name** (given when you create it on the server) - and don't mess around with physical database files and user instances. In that case, your connection string would be something like:

   ```
   Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=StoreManagerDB;Integrated Security=True
   ```

   and everything else is **exactly** the same as before...

Also see Aaron Bertrand's excellent blog post [Bad habits to kick: using AttachDbFileName](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-attachdbfilename/) for more background info.

Comment: And another [discussion of the substitution string usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17147249/why-saving-changes-to-a-database-fails) in your connection and why things seem to not "work",

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the database connection variable is the right syntax and i advise you include an error syntax to show when the db is not connected

Comment: What you mean by the right syntax? This code _pSqlConn.Open();_ executes without error.