# I can't see my new data on report designer

Tags: c#, sql-server, report

I use VS2019 and DevExpress 19.1. I made a few changes on my sql database and then i added new data to my report designer. I'm using datatable. I can see new data on preview but when i run the program  i can't see the new data on my report.I tried to delete my view table on mssql and create again, to delete dataset and create again. Here is my preview and report.

Preview:

[image: Preview photo]

Report:

[image: Report photo]

Thank you.

```
private void Btn_FaturaYazdir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var sorgu = db.VW_FATURALARs.Where(t => t.FATURANO == txt_FaturaNo.Text);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.Tables.Add(LINQToDataTable(sorgu));

        rprSatisFaturasi rpr = new rprSatisFaturasi();
        rpr.DataSource = ds;
        rpr.ShowPreview();
    }
```

That is how i connect my report to the database.
db.VW_FATURALAR is view on database.

[and by this way connect my labels to the database column.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ih3Q9.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why saving changes to a database fails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17147249/why-saving-changes-to-a-database-fails)

Comment: @SMor That's not the same problem i can see my new data on database both SSMS and VS. Even on preview of my report i can see the new data but whenever i run the program and try to see my report, the new data  is not shown on the report but old ones.

Comment: Are your reports hosted on SSRS and are using cached data? If they always need to be as up to date as possible you'll need to ensure they aren't.

Comment: @Larnu I don't save my reports anywhere but the datas inside the report are kept in MSSQL. I don't use SSRS. I design my report througt VS. This catched data thing is only for SSRS? or its is also for VS, MSSQL?

Comment: So what is "the program"?

Comment: @Larnu An accounting program and the report is a bill.

Comment: We can't read your mind, see ANY code, or look over your shoulder. Either the data IS there or it is not. Since it is NOT there, then it seems YOU look in one database and your application looks in another. You should start debugging by looking at your connection string when you attempt to populate / display the report.

Comment: @SMor I editted my question above. I added my cnnection codes and how to connect to column.

Comment: Guys i solved my problem. i hadn't updated my view table on  VS. I had to drag my view table from sql database to VS. Problem is solved. Thank you all.