# SSIS C# Script Task: (Bulk) Insert data from .csv into SQL Server database (preferably using OLEDB)

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

**Problem Stement**

I am trying to completely automate (via parametrization) my SSIS package. It uses the data flow that reads a .csv file and inserts its contents into SQL Server table. So, I need to do this without using the data flow task.

**New setup**

I have replaced the data flow task with a script task that does the same thing.

The .csv file is loaded into the DataTable object and then inserted into the destination table using SqlBulkCopy class and SqlConnection instance.

```
public void Main()
{
    var atlas_source_application = (string)Dts.Variables["$Project::Atlas_SourceApplication"].Value;
    var ssis_package_name = (string)Dts.Variables["System::PackageName"].Value;
    var csv_path = (string)Dts.Variables["$Project::SVM_Directory"].Value;
    var atlas_server_name = (string)Dts.Variables["$Project::AtlasProxy_ServerName"].Value;
    var atlas_init_catalog_name = (string)Dts.Variables["$Project::AtlasProxy_InitialCatalog"].Value;

    var connname = @"Data Source=" + atlas_server_name + ";Initial Catalog=" + atlas_init_catalog_name + ";Integrated Security=SSPI;";
    var csv_file_path = @"" + csv_path + "\\" + ssis_package_name + ".csv";

    try
    {
        DataTable csvData = new DataTable();

        // Part I - Read
        string contents = File.ReadAllText(csv_file_path, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252));

        TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(new StringReader(contents));

        parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
        parser.SetDelimiters(",");

        string[] fields;

        while (!parser.EndOfData)
        {
            fields = parser.ReadFields();

            if (csvData.Columns.Count == 0)
            {
                foreach (string field in fields)
                {
                    csvData.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(field.Trim('\"')) ? null : field.Trim('\"'), typeof(string)));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                csvData.Rows.Add(fields.Select(item => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.Trim('\"')) ? null : item.Trim('\"')).ToArray());
            }


        }

        parser.Close();

        // Part II - Insert
        using (SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection(connname))
        {
            dbConnection.Open();
            using (SqlBulkCopy s = new SqlBulkCopy(dbConnection))
            {
                s.DestinationTableName = "[" + atlas_source_application + "].[" + ssis_package_name + "]";
                foreach (var column in csvData.Columns)
                {
                    s.ColumnMappings.Add(column.ToString(), column.ToString());
                }
                s.WriteToServer(csvData);
            }
        }


        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Dts.Events.FireError(0, "Something went wrong ", ex.ToString(), string.Empty, 0);
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
    }

}
```

This setup works perfectly fine on my local computer. However, once the package is deployed on the server, the insertion part breaks since the database is nowhere to be found (at least that's what it tells me).

Therefore, I tried to imitate the visual SSIS component inside the data flow task [Destination OLE DB] that uses a connection manager.

**Old Setup**

[OLE DB connection manager setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESb4B.png)

[OLE DB destination setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhvW5.png)

This setup uses OLE DB driver with "SQL Server Native Client 11.0" provider (or simply SQLNCLI11.1), "SSPI" integrated security, "Table or view - fast load" mode of access to data. This setup works perfectly fine locally and on the server.

**Desired Setup**

Armed with this knowledge I have tried to use OleDbConnection and OleDbCommand classes [using this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941284/how-to-insert-a-record-into-a-access-table-using-oledb), but I can't see how to use these components to bulk insert data into the DB.

I have also tried to use the visual SSIS component which is called "Bulk Insert Task", but lo luck there either.

How can I possibly insert in bulk using OLE DB?

Comment: Why the limitation "no data flow"? It sounds like you make things way more complicated just because you hit a bump in parameterizing your package.

Comment: The `SqlBulkCopy` in your C# script uses the System.Data.SqlClient` API, not OLEDB. If you need help with the error, post the error message details rather than "breaks since the database is nowhere to be found (at least that's what it tells me)." Of course, you could refactor to use an SSIS data flow natively with OLE DB but that's not a question. Just search for an SSIS tutorial.

Comment: @Filburt We have more than 50 packages to create, so, unfortunately, the limitation of data flows actually push me to code.

Comment: @DanGuzman
I am sorry not to have posted the error message but it's in French, it says that the connection string is wrong or I do not have rights to access. The SSIS server has access to SQL Server (only) via the OLE DB driver.
I am looking for something similar to C# SqlBulkCopy but to be used with C# OLE DB components. I think that I have managed to connect using the mentioned stackoverflow tutorial but I don't seem to advance.

Comment: @BernardoBellotto,what exactly do you mean by "the SSIS server has access to SQL Server (only) via the OLE DB driver"? C# is .NET and can natively access any SQL Server the SSIS server has network connectivity to access.